# add lib to intelliJ project but dont include the lib in artifacts

Tags: intellij-idea, libraries, artifacts

I included my lib in several ways i found online.
The last one i used is based on this:

[Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

However, i don't want the library to be included on export (building artifacts).
At the moment it is which gives problems.

How can i include a library in such a way that it doesn't get included when building artifacts?

Answer (score 4):

Change the [library scope](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) to **Provided** or exclude it from Artifacts by [editing artifact layout](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html).